# ¿Cómo Agregar iconos a la barra de búsqueda rápida?

Tags: java, netbeans, plugin

Recientemente hice un plugin para netbeans basado en un [tutorial para hacer una barra de búsqueda](https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-google.html).

He recibido al sugerencia de convertirlo de barra de búsqueda a una [barra de búsqueda rápida](https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-quick-search.html), pero he notado que no tiene iconos.

¿Existe alguna forma de que al transformar mi barra a la barra de búsqueda rápida y que se muestren los iconos que tenía en la primera barra que hice?

Los iconos tienen undimensiones de `16x16`.

[image: iconos]

La barra de búsqueda rápida se vería similar a

[image: quicksearch]

y me gustaría que se viera algo como

[image: ideal]

Comment: Hola Ruslan, veo que hablas inglés, nunca he tratado de realizar esto en netbeans pero no se si esto es  a lo que te refieras: http://www.pellissier.co.za/hermien/?p=646

Comment: Desafortunadamente no, el componente ya tiene una pariencia personalizada, al migrarlo de barra quedaría en el layer de QuickSearch en vez del de Menú, y quisiera saber si en el layer se puede poner un icono dentro de <folder name="NetBeansZone"> para que al expandir ( https://platform.netbeans.org/images/tutorials/qsearch/72/result-1.png ) salga con icono.

Comment: eh visto esta pregunta por unos dia espero esto te ayude aqui tienes el proyecto del que hablas -> https://github.com/CoderMasters/Jar-Searcher/blob/master/src/web/aprendiendola/toolbar/jarsearch/JarSearchPanel.java creo que la clave esta en esta linea -> addSearchSite("sapjarfinder", "http://sapjarfinder.com/?q=", basePath + "sapjarfinder.gif"); -> donde sapjarfinder.gif es el icono go to Hack. Saludos

Comment: Gracias, en la noche le intento.

Answer (score 3):

Es simple solo llamas al componente y le pones el metodo de setIcon. aqui te dejo un ejemplo.

```
setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(MenuPrincipal.class.getResource("/imagen/Sin t\u00EDtulo-1.png")));
```

Comment: El OP esta hablando del menú  integrado a la IDE Netbeans, no de realizarlo en una applicación.=|